# Safe to Invoke within Form.Dispose() method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I have an `ApplicationContext` with a `Form`. Various asynchronous communication and timing threads may occassionally have a need to restart the application, however before I can restart I have to manually dispose of `MyApplicationContext` which needs to free resources that will be needed *immediately* when the new process starts.

It seems that just calling `Application.Restart()` does not dispose of the resources quickly enough in this case.

Within the call to `MyApplicationContext.Dispose()` the subsequent call to `base.Dispose(disposing)` eventually calls the `Form.Dispose()` method, and because this can originate from various threads I have seen a cross-thread operation exception occur.

```
/// MyApplicationContext.requestRestart()
private void requestRestart()
{
    this.Dispose(); // dispose of applicationcontext
    Application.Restart();
}
```

leads to...

```
/// MyApplicationContext.Dispose(bool)
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) 
{
    /// dispose stuff
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

leads to...

```
/// MainForm.Dispose(bool)
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    /// dispose stuff
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Which can be called from any thread.

Is it safe to `Invoke` the overridden dispose handler on the `Form` UI thread like this?

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => Dispose(disposing)));
    }
    else
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it is not safe to call `Invoke()` from a `Dispose()` implementation.**

Okay, now that I've said that: sure, you could probably get away with it. But it's a really bad idea, and it really could lead to real problems.

The `Dispose()` method is supposed to be *simple*. It should not be accessing managed objects, and it should complete quickly. Calling `Invoke()` can lead to indeterminate delays, depending on what else is going on in the program, and even outright deadlock.

Beyond that, an important rule in the `Dispose()` method is to not access managed objects. At the very least, your implementation needs to check `disposing` first, to ensure that you don't attempt to call `Invoke()` when being called from the finalizer. Furthermore, it's definitely also not a good idea to dispose the object that is currently being used to call the `Invoke()` method. If you really must use cross-thread invocation, the right way to do it would be to retrieve the `SynchronizationContext` for the current object and use that instead of calling `Control.Invoke()`.

But really, the right thing to do here is to fix your restart logic so the entire disposing operation occurs in the UI thread that owns the objects that are being disposed. Your objects aren't the ones that should be responsible to moving execution to the correct thread; the code that *uses* those object should be instead. By the time your `Form` class's code is involved, you should already have made sure the code's executing in the UI thread that owns that object.

Comment: Indeed, I was *getting away* with it.  I think it will be easy enough to move my `requestRestart` method into the `Form` class, such that if a cross-thread invocation is required, it is done at the bottom of the call stack.  But in this case, there is no way to guarantee that the thread that initiates the restart request will be the `Form` UI thread - for example, when network IO arrives.

Comment: You can initiate the restart request anywhere you like, as long as you make sure you have moved to the UI thread before actually _handling_ the cleanup that precedes the restart request. Even there, you may find it useful/desirable to use `SynchronizationContext` instead of a `Form` instance, since presumably that `Form` instance is going to get disposed as part of the cleanup (i.e. you still have the problem of calling `Invoke()` on an object that will be disposed before the `Invoke()` method gets to return).

Comment: I took your good advice and am using the `SynchronizationContext` from the main form.  Thanks Peter.  I feel *much* better about how this is going now.